# corrupt database? ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt, xinput

i have ubuntu 12.04 x86 single boot on an Acer Extensa 5635ZG and when installing Xserver xinput (drivers for xinput controller) it gave an error i dont remeber, after that i haven't been able to install anything at all it always says corrupt data or something like that and tells me to run
and then ....

```
gamerx@gamerx-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get -f  install 
[sudo] password for gamerx: 
reading package list... ready
A construir árvore de dependências       
A ler a informação de estado... Pronto
A corrigir dependências... Feito
Os seguintes pacotes extra serão instalados:
  xserver-xorg-input-joystick
will be updated:
  xserver-xorg-input-joystick
1 pacotes actualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a remover e 4 não actualizados.
1 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
É necessário obter 0 B/22,9 kB de arquivos.
Após esta operação, será libertado 75,8 kB de espaço em disco.
Deseja continuar [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de xserver-xorg-input-joystick:
 xserver-xorg-core (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.1) estraga xserver-xorg-input-joystick (<= 1:1.5.0-3) e é instalado.
  A versão de xserver-xorg-input-joystick a ser configurada é 1:1.3.2-1ubuntu1.
 xserver-xorg-core (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.1) estraga xserver-xorg-input-2.1 e é instalado.
  xserver-xorg-input-joystick (1:1.3.2-1ubuntu1) disponibiliza xserver-xorg-input-2.1.
dpkg: erro ao processar xserver-xorg-input-joystick (--configure):
 problemas com dependências - a deixar por configurar
Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois MaxReports já foi atingido
                                                               Foram encontrados erros enquanto processava:
 xserver-xorg-input-joystick
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

English Translation:

```
The building dependency tree
Reading state information ... ready
Correcting dependencies ... done
The following extra packages will be installed:
   xserver-xorg-input-joystick
will be updated:
   xserver-xorg-input-joystick
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
You must obtain 0 B/22, 9 kB file.
After this operation, will be released 75.8 kB of disk space.
Want to continue [Y / n]? Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-joystick:
  xserver-xorg-core (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10 .1) spoils xserver-xorg-input-joystick (<= 1:1.5.0-3) and is installed.
   The version of xserver-xorg-input-joystick 1:1.3.2 is to be set-1ubuntu1.
  xserver-xorg-core (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10 .1) spoils xserver-xorg-input-2.1 and is installed.
   xserver-xorg-input-joystick (1:1.3.2-1ubuntu1) provides xserver-xorg-input-2.1.
dpkg: error processing xserver-xorg-input-joystick (- configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because it has already been reached MaxReports
                                                                Errors were encountered while processing:
  xserver-xorg-input-joystick
```

plz help me i have no idea how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT]

Try uninstalling the joystick modules

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-joystick
```

Then clean any downloaded package files

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then update your repository list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then attempt to reinstall the package

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-joystick
```